# Connecting load sensors to a custom PCB

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication

I'd like to know if one of [these](https://www.digikey.be/en/products/filter/board-in-direct-wire-to-board/317?s=N4IgjCBcoGwJxVAYygMwIYBsDOBTANCAPZQDaIALGGABxwDsIhVYctTl1bCzXATBF6s%2BMEAF1CABwAuUEAGVpAJwCWAOwDmIAL6EaNRCBSQMOAsTIg%2BFBgGYADOKmzIC5eq26QAWluHjygCu5iSQ5GCOYl7efP5QQSGWAKzi2mlAA) would be suited to connect two sensors like [these](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10245) (two times 3 cables) to my custom pcb or if there is another way? I used to just wire-wrap and then solder these cables directly onto the load cell amplifier but that wasn't really well done and I then just got bad, most of the time completely inaccurate, results from the sensors.

Comment: How did you detemine the connection to be the source of the issue? load cells are sensitive.

Comment: I asked the question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/637316/clarifications-about-pcb-assembly). And the only time my sensors worked, was when the connection was (kinda) well done. Do you have an other idea of where the issue could be coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, an accurate answer is hard to give because the sparkfun page does not include wire guage. IDC connectors are sensitive to that. If you know the guage and buy accordingly, it will be ok. Per your comment and [your other question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/637316/clarifications-about-pcb-assembly), you want to solder this to a readymade PCB, if so, you want to buy a connector that is 0.1" pitch on the board side, or it wont fit. If making your own board, the pitch doesnt matter.

One thing to keep in mind is that you need connector type to be "Individual Wires", as that is how the sensor is wired. Dont buy one for ribbon cables.

Comment: Would something like [this](https://www.digikey.be/en/products/detail/on-shore-technology-inc/OSTVN06A150/1588866) be more suited? I'm sorry I use DigiKey to look these things up, but I'm not quite sure what I should be looking for.

Comment: I think this part would be easy for you and can accomodate a large wire size spectrum. However, the [sparkfun board](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13879) you want to use is 5 pin, so maybe [this](https://www.digikey.be/en/products/detail/on-shore-technology-inc/OSTVN05A150/1588865) would be more suitable. Digikey is completely fine btw.

Comment: Thank you for your help!